# How to pass array as variable outside the wp_query loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

Is there a way to pass an array as a variable out of the wp_query loop? I want to collect post meta from the four posts — next week and the following three weeks. To keep the code clean, I thought it'd be easiest to capture the variable and use the data later in the form.

```
// Capture next week's week number
$nextweek = date("W", strtotime( "+1 week"));

// Query all custom post types
$menu_args = array(
    'post_type'=>'single_menu',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $menu = new WP_Query( $menu_args ); if ( $menu->have_posts() ) : while ( $menu->have_posts() ) : $menu->the_post();

    // Get custom fields
    $menuids = array( get_post_field( 'week', $post->id ) );
    $titles = array( get_post( $post->id )->post_title ); 
    $choosefrom = array( get_post_field( 'menu_listing', $post->id ) );
    $selection = array( get_post_field( $checkout_menu, $post->id ) );

    // Create new array with custom fields  
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $menuids as $id => $menuid ) {
        $result[$menuid] = array(
            'title'  => $titles[$id],
            'offering'  => $choosefrom[$id],
            'menu' => $selection[$id],
            'delivery'    => 0,
        );
    }

    // Return the arrays for specified weeks
    for ($i = $nextweek; $i<$nextweek+4; $i++) {
    if ( $result[$menuid] == $result[$i] ) {
        print_r( $result );
    }
    }

    endwhile;   
    endif;
```

`print_r()` returns the correct results, my `$results` array for the next four weeks. However, when I create a variable and call it outside the loop, like below, I only get the last/fourth `$result` in the array:

```
    for ($i = $nextweek; $i<$nextweek+4; $i++) {
    if ( $result[$menuid] == $result[$i] ) {

        $payload = $result;
    }
  }

endwhile;   
endif;

print_r( $payload );
```

Same thing happens when I create a new array like so:

```
    $payload = array();
    for ($i = $nextweek; $i<$nextweek+4; $i++) {
    if ( $result[$menuid] == $result[$i] ) {

        $payload[] = $result;
    }
  }

endwhile;   
endif;

print_r( $payload );
```

If I concatenate the variable like `$payload .= $result;`, I get `ArrayArrayArrayArray` returned.

I know I can echo the form inside loop, but would rather take the array as a data variable if at all possible. Am I missing something easy?

Comment: Are you simply looking for the `$posts` property ...? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties

Comment: I am having trouble passing the data array I created out of the `endwhile` and `endif` loop. How might the `$posts` property help me achieve this?

Comment: Not really sure what your problem is then ... is it maybe simply how to _add_ new elements to an array in a loop, instead of _overwriting_ variables in each iteration ...? If so, that's rather trivial to research, https://www.google.com/search?q=php+how+to+add+new+elements+to+an+array+in+a+loop

Comment: Well, thank you for pointing out this should be easy. Turns out my problem was that I needed to put `payload = array();` OUTSIDE of the loop. You helped me to stop over-thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$result initialized every loop iteration. Your $result contain only one item. Same think for $payload variable.
Outside of while loop you have only the last item. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we can't see straight ... `$payload = array();` needed to be placed outside of the wp_query, before `$menu_args`.